# xcode swift parsing text like in php or perl

Tags: macos, swift, xcode6

Could you  point me to to a tutorial or code example for processing text strings in Swift? Like searching strings with patterns, exploding/splitting string on a separator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you are going to find RegEx luke stuff, but here are a couple of resources:

http://www.learnswiftonline.com/reference-guides/string-reference-guide-for-swift/

http://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-strings/

Comment: Excellent reference for swift beginners like me.